# Front-End BlogPost Form in Mezzanine

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement a BlogPost View to add posts in the frontend of my mezzanine project. The quick blog form that can be found here is the form I'm trying to create a view with.
https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/blog/forms.py

added the following line to urls.py:

```
url("^%sadd%s$" % _slashes, "blog_post_add", name="blog_post_add"),
```

added this function to views.py:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def blog_post_add(request):
    form = BlogPostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        BlogPost = form.save(commit=False)
        BlogPost.save()
        return redirect(BlogPost)
    return render_to_response('blog/blog_post_add.html',
                              { 'form': form },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

That's all I changed in these files. https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/blog/urls.py

Did I miss anything completely? I'm not receiving any errors, it's simply not working.
Thanks for any help and sorry - I'm quite new to Python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in your settings.py

```
BLOG_SLUG = "/"
APPEND_SLASH = "/"
```

UPDATE:

```
url("^add%s$" % _slashes[1], "blog_post_add", name="blog_post_add"),
//this is equivalent to url("^add/$", "blog_post_add", name="blog_post_add")
```

In the mezzanine implementation for slashes:

```
_slashes = (
    "/" if settings.BLOG_SLUG else "",
    "/" if settings.APPEND_SLASH else "",
)
```

`if BLOG_SLUG is True and not EMPTY then it is equivalent to "/", the same also in APPEND_SLASH`